# How to install Windows 7, Windows XP and Ubuntu to an external hard drive from a Mac?

Tags: windows-7, macos, ubuntu, windows-xp, external-hard-drive

I have Macbook Pro. I have a portable USB hard drive and I want to install

- Windows 7
- Windows XP
- Ubuntu

on that portable hard drive.

Does anybody know how to install all three operating systems on the drive? I do not want to touch my Mac hard disk or OS X.

Comment: bear in mind, even if this is possible, running an OS like Windows over USB would be painfully slow.

Comment: @tombull89 slow is ok for me.

Comment: Windows XP will not run on a USB device without some serious hacking.

Comment: For the Linux part, use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). It's a dead-simple application to use. You go through the wizard, select the Ubuntu ISO file, select the distribution and the external hard-drive, and you're set. For Windows 7, here is [a very detailed howto](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7vista-from-usb-drive-detailed-100-working-guide/), but it requires a Windows installation to begin with. I'm not too sure it'll just run on the Mac without any further hacking.

Comment: @slhck I don't want bootable windows. I just want to install windows on an external hard drive instead of internal because my internal has mac osx and I don't want to touch it.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to defragment and then partition your hard drive.

It's virtually impossible and really impractical to run Windows off an external/flash drive. If it's for programs that do not require much computing power, use VMware or Fusion...